# php5 files (with apache2 running on aws amazon ec2 suse) subdirectories seems to be blocked

Tags: php, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, apache2, suse

I have a problem with an Aws Amazon-EC2 SuSe instance, installed apache2, php5, mysql and everything needed to run a web application, we're able to see simple .html or .php pages, but when we try to view more "elaborated" pages with "incredibly complicated code" (excuse the sarcasm) like this

```
<link href="css/XXXX.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

or

```
<div style="background-image:url(img/XXXXX.png);>
```

or

```
<?php include('inc/XXXX.php'); ?>
```

or

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/XXXXX.js"></script>
```

or any other code (html, php, js, whatever) that points to a subdirectory (css,js,inc,img and so on) doesn't work (all response it's a nice blank page without any error messages like 404 or 403), if i move any necessary file to the root directory seems to work fine, and of course I'm not going to maintain a site with more than 3000 files at root.

Not sure if I'm missing any configuration at SuSe, Apache or PHP .conf files but already googled this question but i can't find anything (maybe I'm a little stressed with this and do not see the answer) to solve this to be able to maintain a "normal" directory structure, somebody can help me? thnxs a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you have a .htaccess file in the root of the vhost and that is causing this problem!

Comment: thnxs @rsz but the problem was something more simple that i don't understand why was happening, the main idea is that the instance of suse was blocking all subdirectories by default, when i ran the chmod and chown for vroot directory the inherit of permissions for sudirectories and content was blocked even using -R parameter and root access. The solution (not too wise i know) was removing and reinstalling some security modules on Suse. Now it's solved but this is the first time that something like this happens to me.